# Losing mysql result resource after first use

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code: (query added)

```
$weight_table = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM ".$prefix."weight ORDER BY wlimit DESC");    
foreach ($weight as $area => $weight) {
        echo $weight;

        while ($weight_row = mysql_fetch_array($weight_table)) {
            print_r($weight_row);
            $limit = $weight_row['wlimit'];
            if ($weight < $limit) {
        $weight_level[$count] = $weight_row;
            }
        }
    }
    print_r($weight_level);
```

Where $weight_table is a mysql query result and $weight is an array.

My problem is that $weight_table seems to be expiring after the first while loop, so that the $weight array is effectively treated as having one item. This is a problem!

Can anyone suggest why php would forget a mysql result after the first use?

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest that. I only meant that not getting the right result was a problem. I simply assumed there was a flag set wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first iteration through the for loop, you're fetching all of the records from the mysql result set.   Your inner while loop will run until all the rows are gone.  How many rows do you want it to pull?

Also you're re-using $weight which is a bad idea and may be causing side effects.

```
foreach ($weight as $area => $wt) { 
   echo $wt; 

   while ($weight_row = mysql_fetch_array($weight_table)) { 
      print_r($weight_row); 
      $limit = $weight_row['wlimit']; 
      if ($wt < $limit) { 
         $weight_level[$count] = $weight_row; 
      } 
   } 

   mysql_data_seek($weight_table,0);
} 
print_r($weight_level);
```

Comment: I want to pull everything, once for each value in the $weight array. It seems to give up after the first value. Also, changed the $weight variable as above.

Comment: Is there anything in the php setup that could affect this? I think it was working a while ago.

Comment: @YsoL8: Your MySQL-query (and result) are fine?

Comment: Simply add mysql_data_seek($weight_table,0); after the While loop completes, so next iteration it will be back at the start.

Comment: @fosco That has cleared the problem. (Will need to test it further of course). What does it do?

Comment: It resets the query result set back to the beginning so that you can fetch them all again.

Answer (score 1):

You override `$weight` array in the foreach declaration.
Use `$area => $_weight` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($weight_row = mysql_fetch_array($weight_table)) {
    print_r($weight_row);
    foreach ($weights as $area => $weight) {
        echo $weight;
       $limit = $weight_row['wlimit'];
       if ($weight < $limit) {
          $weight_level[$count] = $weight_row;
       }
   }
}
print_r($weight_level);
```

Use $weight array as $weights

Comment: Switching the while and foreach loops distorts the contents of $weight_level

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($weight as $area => $weight) {
```

You're overwriting what was in your `$height` array, which is why it is expiring after the first run through your loop. Try using another variable name for one or the other.